# Immersive mode on Jelly Bean - Menu bar not disappearing

Tags: android

I'm using the sample code in the Android documentation to make my activity full screen:

```
// This snippet hides the system bars.
private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}

// This snippet shows the system bars. It does this by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    hideSystemUI();
}
```

This works on launch. When I tap the screen, the menus appear, with a transparent status bar and a non-transparent nav bar. The problem is, it doesn't then time out and go away, as the docs indicate it should. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Immersive mode is for KitKat 4.4 and above. I don't think there is any 3rd party api to make it work below 4.4.

Well you could use full screen mode for android< 4.4 nd immersive mode for above.

Set an uiVisibilityChangeListner .

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                if(visibility == 0) {
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```